# MVC - How to pass model from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working with a model that needs to flow through a series of controllers and views manipulating it along the way(Only loading it on the first controller).  Is there a way to persist the model from the view back down to a controller and so forth?

Here is my code.

Model:

```
    public class ROWModel
{
    #region Properties
    //Request
    public List<TBLRETURNABLEITEMS> TBLRETURNABLEITEMS { get; set; }
    //public List<ReturnReasons> ReturnReasons { get; set; }

    public int Order_No { get; set; }
    public string First_Name {get; set; }
    public string Last_Name {get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Address_1 { get; set; }
    public string Address_2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Postal_Code { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCode {get; set; }
    public string TerritoryCode {get; set; }


    //Post

    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public ROWModel()
    { }
    #endregion
}

public class ReturnableItems : IComparable<ReturnableItems>
{
    private int _id;
    private decimal _ordered;
    private decimal _shipped;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    public decimal Ordered
    {
        get { return _ordered; }
        set { _ordered = value; }
    }

    public decimal Shipped
    {
        get { return _shipped; }
        set { _shipped = value; }
    }
```

}

After populating the model and sending it to the view everything is displayed using the model as it should be.  I think stick the model like so on the form tag:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Items", "ROW", Model))
```

Here is the post Items Action of the ROW controller:

```
    [ActionName("Items"), AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Items(ROWModel model, FormCollection collection)
```

Problem is Model doesn't return the list of TBLRETURNABLEITEMS i populated it with initially.  It keeps the other properties i populated but not the list.  How do i maintain this model's data without having to reload it on every controller should i want to.

Comment: Can't you just add the view model type as an argument on a Action method?

public ActionResult ActionOnSecondController(MyViewModel model) {...}

Comment: Thought i could to, but i don't get any of the List<TBLRETURNABLEITEMS> items back.  Could this be because i am using a partial class to display the List<TBLRETURNABLEITEMS> items?  I wouldn't thinks so since both the view and the partial inherit from the model.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that you can use TempData for that.

So something like this:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult TestA()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        model.Something = "Test";
        return View(model);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult TestA(MyModel model)
    {
        TempData["MyModel"] = model;
        return RedirectToAction("TestB");
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult TestB()
    {
        MyModel myModel = (MyModel)TempData["MyModel"];
        return View(myModel);
    }
```

Comment: You were the first to answer correctly.  TempData is an accurate solution for this issue.  After a little more research however, probably not a good idea for my situation due to db concurrency and our site sitting on load balanced server.

Comment: If you're trying to pass a complex object you'll also need to serialize it.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48641517/2521004)

Answer (score 3):

**NerdDinner Step 6: ViewData and ViewModel**
http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm

Comment: Thank you for your response, however i don't want to entirely reload the model on every controller action.  Just the initial.  Don't see anything in this link detailing that.

Comment: OK.  But how do you deal with concurrency issues?  What happens if someone edits the data between your page views?

Comment: That's a good point.  Guess it looks like i might be headed down the road i didn't want to have to go down and that is databasing and reloading on each controller action.

Answer (score 1):

You can use session for this kind of problems.
or you can use tempdata if the posts are sequential .
and  fetching each time from DB works if you run application in Intranet networks.

Answer (score -1):

Getting a model (any model) from the view to the controller is pretty simple.

Others on here have covered that part where you take in a model object as a param.

what you seem to be missing is the binding of the list, which happens based on the names in your form elements in the view.  basically,they have to look like C# list elements as strings.  So, not knowing any of the properties of your list elements, something like:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("model.TBLRETURNABLEITEMS[0].ItemId") %>
```

Obviously,that's just a string, so you can construct it in a loop to do many rows of returnables.

Comment: given my code above how would you incorporate this.  I am still having trouble submitting the model and getting any items to appear in TBLRETURNABLEITEMS.  Although i may not go down this route for database concurrency issues this would still answer my initial question.

Answer (score -1):

I think in MVC as well session is a handy option instead of firefighting with the return to action with Viewmodel.

Comment: Please explain your answer.