# Error 500 when using TempData in .NET Core MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tempdata

Hello i am trying to  add an object to `TempData` and redirect to another controller-action. I get error message 500 when using `TempData`.

```
public IActionResult Attach(long Id)
{
    Story searchedStory=this.context.Stories.Find(Id);
    if(searchedStory!=null)
    {
        TempData["tStory"]=searchedStory;  //JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchedStory) gets no error and passes 

        return RedirectToAction("Index","Location");
    }
    return View("Index");
}


public IActionResult Index(object _story) 
{             
    Story story=TempData["tStory"] as Story;
    if(story !=null)
    {
    List<Location> Locations = this.context.Locations.ToList();
    ViewBag._story =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(story);
    ViewBag.rstory=story;
    return View(context.Locations);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Story");
}
```

P.S Reading through possible solutions I have added  `app.UseSession()` to the `Configure` method and `services.AddServices()` in the `ConfigureServices` method but to no avail.Are there any obscure settings i must be aware of?

P.S adding `ConfigureServices` and `UseSession`

**ConfigureServices**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddOptions();
                services.AddDbContext<TreasureContext>(x=>x.UseMySql(connectionString:Constrings[3]));
                services.AddMvc();
                services.AddSession();
            }
```

**Configure**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Comment: Please post your Startup.ConfigureServices and Startup.Configure methods.

Comment: I did post them already.

Comment: There is *never* just an error 500 without any error message. Look at your logs, and understand what the *actual error* is. And if you cannot find a solution, make sure to include the full error message in your question.

Comment: Please be sure to read up on [how to use TempData correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12422930/215552)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing  `services.AddMemoryCache();` line in your ConfigureServices() method. Like this:

```
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddMvc();
```

And after that TempData should be working as expected.

Comment: *A note for Asp.net Core 3 users* This solution will not work for you, instead refer to Agrawal Shraddha solution.

Comment: @MohammedA.Fadil This solution WILL work in Mvc Core 3 application. Please do you research first before commenting.

Comment: I did my research, your solution did not work for me. And after trial and error Agrawal Shraddha solution worked pefectly for me on 3.1

Comment: With all due respect solution I've provided works in my MVC.NET Core 3 application just fine as we speak.:)  So to say, that "This solution will not work for Asp.net Core 3 users" is a bit of a stretch, because app I am working on is living contradiction to your statement. Happy programming!:)

Comment: Nothing personal bro. Good luck

Comment: @MohammedA.Fadil I can confirm, that this is not working for Core 3.1.

Answer (score 24):

You have to serialize the object before assigning it to TempData as core only support strings and not complex objects.

```
TempData["UserData"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchedStory);
```

and retrieve the object by deserializing it.

```
var story = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Story>(TempData["searchedStory"].ToString())
```

Comment: This was my issue and it was driving me crazy. Using complex object has caused me to return 500 error without any exceptions or explanation of any it was returning 500. Serializing it was the way to go.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for saving the day :D

Answer (score 3):

I am working on Dot net 5.0(which is in preview currently). In my case, none of the configuration mentioned in above answers didn't work. TempData was causing XHR object to receive 500 Internal server error in Dot net 5.0 MVC app. Finally, I found that, the missing part was AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()

```
`public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddBrowserDetection();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews().
                .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
        }`
```

It is important to add sessions while using TempData, as TempData internally makes use of Session variable to store data. Here, answer by @Agrawal Shraddha is also very valid. Asp.Net Core/Dot net 5.0 doesn't support TempData to directly store complex objects. Instead, it has to serialize to Json string and needs to be deserialized again while retrieving it.

```
`TempData[DATA] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataObject);`
```

And Configure() method as below:

```
`public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
`
```

For more information on TempData configuration settings, to make it to work, refer below post:
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tempdata

Answer (score 1):

Add a TempData extension just like Sesssion to serialize and de-serialize

```
    public static class TempDataExtensions
    {
        public static void Set<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key, T value)
        {
           string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
           tempData.Add(key, json);
        }

        public static T Get<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key)
        {
            if (!tempData.ContainsKey(key)) return default(T);

            var value = tempData[key] as string;

            return value == null ? default(T) :JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
```